# Gulp task (babel, uglify) not processing simple JS file - how can I find out why?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

So, I have a gulp file and workflow that I re-use each time I start a new project, and it works every time ... until now.

One of the gulp tasks, which I have simply named 'js', processes any .js files and copies to the equivalent directory inside my 'dist' directory.

This is the gulp task:

```
gulp.task('js', () => {
    gulp.src('app/**/*.js')
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```

But it's not creating the file in dist (even though terminal says it starts and finishes.

I have tried to narrow it down to code inside the single .js file that I am processing and it's very weird. I literally stripped everything out and got to this:

```
alert("hi");
console.log("hello");
```

was processed and created:

```
alert("hi");console.log("hello");
```

But if I clear that out and do something even as simple as:

```
let a=1;
let b=2;
```

It does not create a file. I am very confused about this! I mean, I can't make it any simpler, really!

Comment: What do your Babel options look like (your `.babelrc` file or similar)? What version of Babel and any Babel plugins/presets are you using? There really isn't any error? (Could you have something redirected that's hiding the error?)

Comment: Any errors on execution? Maybe there is some not processable code?

Comment: The fact that it *seems* to break on ES2015+ code is significant. Could you double-check what happens if you change those `let`s to `var`? My guess is it processes the file and puts it (largely unchanged) into `dist`. Separately: What if you add a `console.log` to that so that it's not just variable declarations?

Comment: .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist')).pipe(connect.reload());  <== connect is a import from 'gulp-connect'..(looks like.. import connect from 'gulp-connect'), can you try this

Comment: Stack Overflow is a **very** active place. When you post a question (or an answer), *stick around* for a few minutes to answer queries that come up in the comments.

Comment: TJ - Aha, yes, changed the let statements to var and it worked. Also included console.log and all three lines came through in the file in dist/js/

Comment: TJ - here's what I have in the package.json file (excerpt):

  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-real-favicon": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-sitemap": "^6.0.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-webp": "^3.0.0",
    "pump": "^3.0.0",
    "run-sequence": "^2.2.1"
  },

Comment: Sorry, formatting flattened that all out ^

Comment: OK, I compared this workspace with other that was working fine - I was missing .babelsrc file - all working now :)